# Send Push Notifications App in App Store public

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

Sorry, I'm a newbie about that and I found nothing. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) and everything works fine. Now my app is in the app store available. How to send the push notifications to all the users? I am somewhat bemused about the "Enter device token"-Field in the [Push Notifications Tool](https://github.com/onmyway133/PushNotifications/blob/master/Screenshots/iOSCertificate.png). Why should I enter a device-token, I want to send the notifications to the users, not only to my device? Or did I understand something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to send a push notification your `Push Notification Tool` needs to know to which device it has to send the notification. For this you need to have `Device Token`. You can have multiple `Device Token` for each user, and your `Push Notification Tool` will push a notification to all devices whose `Device Token` is stored. You cannot send a push notification based on the `user id` or other such fields.

**EDIT:**

This is how you can get the deviceToken. You need to add this function in your `AppDelegate`

```
func application(
  _ application: UIApplication,
  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
) {
  let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
  let token = tokenParts.joined()
  print("Device Token: \(token)")
}
```

**Note:**
Make sure you have followed the tutorial you have mentioned in your question. You need to register for notifications and follow all the steps required to set up the push notification on your app. The above function may not work if your app has not registered for Push notification. I have posted only one method, assuming that you have followed and implemented everything from the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you!! Where can I get the device token from the users? My device token will be print in the console, but from the users?

Comment: Thanks bro, I followed the tutorial and this function is already in my AppDelegate and the push notifications works fine. I have the device token of my device, yeah, but HOW can I see the device token from the users to put it in the push notifications tool? Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: You need to write a function to store the `Device Token` in your backend. As soon as you get the `Device Token` send it to your backend and then fetch a specific users `Device Token` from there to send a `Push Notification` using the `Push Notification Tool`.

Comment: Thats it! Thank you very much! When I have multiple device token from, for example, 100 users; for each user I need to send a notifications, or can I send ONE notification to ALL users? And I need only to store the device token, right? Nothing to do in the Apple Developer Center?

Comment: Yes you can have an array of `Device Token` and then use a loop to send notifications to all those `Token's`. And apart from the configurations & settings you need to do in Apple Developer Center that are mentioned in the tutorial, you don't need Apple Developer Center to send or Receive push notifications.

If this solved your issue please mark this as the answer and upvote.

Comment: Of course I will do! Just the last question: You said I can use a loop to send notifications to all those Tokens. How is this possible? I can only send notifications with the push notifications tool or is there another way?

Comment: I normally use my server to make the `Push` but if you had to do it using `Push Notification Tool` then you need to see if it supports multiple `Device Token`. Try adding `Device Token` in this format and see if it takes it `Token01,Token02,Token03,.....` If not then you may have to look at other services. You can also use `Postman` app on Mac to test push notifications.